# Sort strings by length in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I am aware there are other questions like this, but they don't work hence this question.

I am trying to sort an array of strings by their length (descending) and I have been trying to use `qsort` as that is what is suggested, but every solution doesn't work for me. I believe the reason is because in all the examples of using `qsort` they have an array as such;

```
char *arrayOfStrings...
```

but my array starts as such

```
char **arrayOfStrings;
```

this is because I am dynamically adding the strings to the array but either way I can't seem to get `qsort` to sort the strings in order.

Code for reference:

```
int numberOfStrings = 0;
int numberOfStringsTwo = 0;
int totalNoStrings = 0;

scanf("%d", &numberOfStrings);
totalNoStrings += numberOfStrings;
char **inputArray = malloc(numberOfStrings * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++) {
    char input[100];
    scanf("%s", input);
    inputArray[i] = (char *)malloc((strlen(input) + 1));
    strcpy(inputArray[i], input);
}

scanf("%d", &numberOfStringsTwo);
totalNoStrings += numberOfStringsTwo;
inputArray = realloc(inputArray, totalNoStrings * sizeof(char*));
for (int j = numberOfStrings; j < totalNoStrings; j++) {
    char input[100];
    scanf("%s", input);
    inputArray[j] = (char *)malloc((strlen(input) + 1));
    strcpy(inputArray[j], input);
}

qsort(inputArray, totalNoStrings, sizeof(char *), compareStrings);

size_t z;
for (z = 0; z < totalNoStrings; z++) {
    printf("%s\n", inputArray[z]);
}
```

and

```
int compareStrings(const void *one, const void *two) {
    const char *iOne = (const char*)one;
    const char *iTwo = (const char*)two;
    return strcmp(iOne, iTwo);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code above? What does your test data look like, what results do you expect, and what results do you get? "Here's my code, debug it for me" doesn't get you much sympathy.

Comment: Your `compareStrings` function doesn't do a comparison based on the length. It compares the strings. Also, have you single-stepped this in the debugger?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? Does it not compile? Does it crash on input? Does it give incorrect output? You have to give us more than "It doesn't work." We're here to help you find and fix the problem, not do all your thinking for you.

Comment: if you want to sort based on "length" then why does compareStrings calls the strcmp? You should make the comparison based on their length, i.e, strlen(iOne) < strlen(iTwo)

Comment: @KyloR A good example of why *understanding* how the code you did *not* write actually works before using it. Doesn't mean you know everything, but at least know what it *does*. Fortunately in this case it is a simple fix.

Comment: @KyloR Excellent. Knowing why something does *not* work is as important as knowing why something else *does* .

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

The `compareStringLens()` function is incorrect: it receives pointers to the string pointers, you miss one level of indirection in your code, calling `strlen` on the address of a pointer has undefined behavior.

Here is a comparison function that sorts strings in decreasing length and lexicographical order for the each length:

```
int compareStrings(const void *one, const void *two) {
    const char *iOne = *(const char * const *)one;
    const char *iTwo = *(const char * const *)two;
    size_t len1 = strlen(iOne);
    size_t len2 = strlen(iTwo);
    if (len1 > len2)
        return -1;
    if (len2 > len1)
        return +1;
    return strcmp(iOne, iTwo);
}
```

Comment: Note: If strictly length is required as comparison (descending) and equal length regardless of content is considered equivalent, the last five lines can simply be `return (len1 > len2) ? -1 : (len2 > len1);`. Regardless, nice answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I agree the comparison function is more precise than strictly required, but it is usually a good thing to implement a total order so the behavior is reproducible.

Comment: Could someone explain how casting works in the `*(const char * const *) one` Couldn't really understand (